# play a sound on iphone/android

Tags: android, iphone, audio

For some art thing there will be a video screen showing animated typography of the movie 12 angry men. This is at a place where people can drink and talk so we want to provide the sound in another way.

We where thinking of sending it to the iphone/android of people.
This in a way that people can go to a website or something and that the sound will be played of the part where the movie is at (so they don't have to search for 40 minutes).
Maybe providing a little tweaking would be good in case it's out of sync.

However none of the people working on the project has experience which such thing.
So i wondered if people had ideas/tips. Like live podcast, or library's or just telling what the hardest part will be.

edit:

how would you do it?

Comment: I don't see a question (or a question mark) in this entire post.

Comment: I wonder if [Icecast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icecast) is supported with reasonable software on modern smartphones?

Comment: "So i wondered if people had ideas/tips. Like live podcast, or library's or just telling what the hardest part will be."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hosting some sort of streaming audio like a live podcast seems like as fine a way as any to achieve what you are after. Look in to live streaming platforms, Ustream is one of them I believe.

If you can find one that already works in the browser on the the devices you intend to support then you won't have to worry about creating the program to consume your stream, you can simply direct people to the URL

But there is no specific question here that we can help with.